# Should we be converting to PostgreSQL from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Now that MySQL is in Oracle's hands, do you think it's a good idea to switch to using PostgreSQL for new applications instead? (Also what do you think about converting existing applications?)

I've used both DB systems before and while PostgreSQL is great for it's licensing terms and standards compliance, MySQL is definitely easier to get up and running quickly. (I make this as a personal observation, I know you might disagree...)

Edit:

I should clarify... I don't want this to be a MySQL/PostgreSQL is better than PostgreSQL/MySQL debate. I like both DB systems and am happy using both (and really for the complexity of most of the applications I'm working on, it's much of a muchness). I'm just in a position where I'm trying to look forward and consider the stability of my technology base before committing myself to a particular course. If you have gone through a similar process and have some kind of migration plan in mind I would like to hear from you regarding what that is and why you decided on it.

Comment: You're going to have to give some context if you expect any type of insightful answer.  As it stands, you're just asking people to climb aboard their respective soapboxes.

Comment: Sure, I'm mainly trying to understand if other developers are worried about ongoing support for MySQL as it is a competitor to Oracle's other product lines. I've seen a similar trend away from Netbeans as an IDE and I want to know if people think it's wise to move on from MySQL (it doesn't have to be to PostgreSQL, I just picked that since it's another popular OS DB choice...)

Comment: Subjective ("personal observation"), argumentative (I might disagree), with a good dose of "question asks to predict the future".

Comment: I understand your concerns Greg, but I don't really want to start new projects (or continue developing existing ones) without thinking about the stability  of my technology base. Yes it's subjective, but I'm not asking people to tell me which DB is better. I just want to know if others are making migration plans and why...

Comment: I found MySQL to be much harder to install than PostgreSQL.. On ArchLinux anyway..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at it this way: regardless of what Oracle *says*, the fact remains that they *could* decide to do Something Bad with MySQL at any time.  Maybe they will, and maybe they won't, but why take the risk (for new projects, at least) when you can just use PostgreSQL?

Given the choice, I'd just as soon go with Postgres myself. It seems to be a very stable project upon which to base my own work.  Long history, under active development, good documentation, etc.

Since you've indicated that you're happy working with either one, I say go with Postgres for new projects and don't worry about converting existing projects unless and until Oracle does something with MySQL that gives you cause for concern.

Answer (score 6):

Installing is a one-time-job ... kindof. Depends ofcourse. but PostgreSQL isn't much harder to install than MySQL, if harder at all. It's the day-to-day cost of ownership that matters. As a developer I prefer PostgreSQL over MySQL, as the latter behaves different from version to version (they're still playing catchup to the sql standard and probably always will). Also MySQL is a pain to administer sometime. What does it matter if it takes ten minutes more to install if you must wait for hours when adding a column to a table or other trivial tasks. Finally I think the mysql-environment was too turbulent even before the Oracle takeover, with Oracle already owning innoDB, MariaDB. I think it is a general mess. So yes, I'd migrate, but for other reasons.

If you actually prefer MySQL over PostgreSQL I'd lay out a migration plan just to be ready if need arises, as a kind of lazy proactiveness ...

Answer (score 2):

I am no fan of Oracle, but the company has come forward with a [10 point commitment to existing MySQL customers](http://www.marketwire.com/press-release/Oracle-Makes-Commitments-to-Customers-Developers-and-Users-of-MySQL-NASDAQ-ORCL-1090000.htm).

So at least as of now, I don't see any cause for worry. Any database migration will require some effort and cost in terms of time and money. So if I were you, I'd hold on for a while before doing anything drastic as a database migration.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. Maybe I should just be worrying about my new projects then...

Answer (score 2):

Even if MySQL does go south, there's MariaDB, which was started by the founder of MySQL. It's a drop in replacement and has some quite exciting new features.

http://askmonty.org/wiki/index.php/MariaDB

I've been giving a go on my development environment and I've been liking it so far.

Comment: Looks really interesting. I didn't know about this... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the article:

**[Save MySQL by letting Oracle keep it GPL](http://www.pythian.com/news/6747/save-mysql-by-letting-oracle-keep-it-gpl/)**

This answers your question amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

Good lord.

O.k. so let's just get it in the open. I am not a MySQL fan. I think its broken. However I am biased (http://www.commandprompt.com/). That said here are the benefits of PostgreSQL.

1. PostgreSQL scales farther than MySQL. MySQL does really well if you have a limited number of CPUs. If you get above 4, PostgreSQL will just go farther, longer.
2. PostgreSQL's license allows it to never be bought. You don't have to worry about a single entity taking it over. At present there are at least a dozen actively supporting companies including, Red Hat, PgExperts, Command Prompt, OmniTI, EnterpriseDB, Fujitsu and Oracle (yep).
3. PostgreSQL's feature set is remarkable. Just look at it.

However, and this is the most important. Do what your business requires. MySQL is a decent database when used for its purpose.

Comment: -1 for repeating all Postgres vs MySQL arguments over and over again. Getting tired of it, so -1.